# How can I remove an email from my Google account?

Tags: gmail

I just signed into Chrome on a new computer (my work laptop got reimaged) and suddenly I got an email from Google via my --work-- email that said I had signed in.

I like that I get these emails. But I don't like that it's going to a work email. I went to myaccount.google.com (following [these steps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/76143?hl=en) but my work email wasn't there.)

How can I remove my work email from my Google account?

Comment: Do you have any forwarding rule or filter forwarding messages from a Google email to your work email?

Comment: No, I don't. As far as I know, my Gmail knows nothing of my work email except as a sometimes conversation partner (as I perhaps send emails to myself, or as people send things to both my work and gmail). I do have my.name@gmail.com attached to the google account (not primary), and my work email is my.name@mywork.com so it's possible I typed the work email by muscle memory. But that shouldn't make it a recipient of these emails.

Comment: Bizarre. Your email client can show the source of the message, with various details about its path from Google to you. Maybe it can offer a clue.

Comment: @corsika: If you need help to found the details mentioned by Homegrown Tomato, add the [message headers](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22454?hl=en). You can mask your username and last digits of the IP addresses to protect your privacy but don't remove the email addresses domains.

Comment: Nothing abnormal for the message headers. It's clearly intended to go to my work email address, and does so directly (after passing through my work's scanners and dmz, it looks like). It wants to send it to my work email.